# The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://management.azure.com/.default' does not exist

Tags: c#, azure, webapi

I am trying to get an access token on behalf of the login user for azure service management but always getting this error.

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://management.azure.com/.default' does not exist.

I have tried a different combination of scopes, only `User.Read` is working fine.

Below permission has been assigned to the app already.
[image]

Comment: also tried scop  https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation but the same error **AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation' does not exist.**

Comment: Scope `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` should have worked. In fact, I was doing it just a few days ago and it works flawlessly. Can you edit your question and provide more details about your application?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes you are right it's working now. it was not working because I was using my personal account for login instead of my work account.

Answer (score 0):

For scop **https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation** to work, the login user must be an AD user on behalf of which access token is being requested.